# Using .load() in jQuery 1.9+

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

jQuery [.load() was deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) in version 1.8.

If I wanted to perform the following task:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

How would I do this in jQuery 1.9+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was just a shortcut to the equivalent `.on` call, so use that instead:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    // run code
});
```

If you don't care about multiple handlers, you can go with the basic `window.onload = function...`.